# Difference between 'Orbit' and 'Globe' in eye anatomy?

Tags: eyes, nomenclature, neuroanatomy

What's the difference between 'Orbit' and 'Globe' in eye's anatomy. Do they refer to the same ? I encountered this in this text:

> ... ciliary ganglion, which is approximately 3 mm in size, and located
>   2-3 mm posterior to the globe and lateral to the optic nerve,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a rough answer myself:

> The globe of the eye, or bulbus oculi, is the eyeball **apart from its
>   appendages**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globe_%28human_eye%29

> ... the orbit is the **cavity or socket of the skull** in which the eye and
>   **its appendages** are situated. "Orbit" can refer to the bony socket, or it can also be used to imply the contents.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_%28anatomy%29

Comment: Hi, please don't offer bounties on [questions](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9941/1306) that are 1) [Off topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and 2) [bad questions](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This site is not for medical advice and the question does not give the information needed to make it answerable.

Comment: @terdon I understand that the question might not be on-topic or a good question, but offering a bounty could even help this improved. When a question didn't receive any attention, it can neither be improved nor the asker can be trained. There are many options in this website to train people to ask good questions. You even changed the title of two links you provided to sound 'pessimistic'. Instead of comparative commands, I think it would be better if you just train people with optimism and provide the links accordingly.

Comment: Well yes, if you think you can improve it _edit_ it. However, personal medicine is very correctly off topic here, we are not MDs and do not have access to the patient. If people base their treatment on our answers, they can cause themselves serious harm. A mod has asked for more information on that question and none has been offered. If this is someone you know _tell_ them how to improve the question. Adding a bounty is not helpful in this situation.